# A name for a connector plug that cannot be accidentally disconnected?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There is a little knob on top of [RJ connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack), for example, the RJ45 Ethernet connector. I guess the function of this knob is to keep the connector plugged in even if the wire is accidentally tugged away.

Is there a name for the knob in particular, or for such a connector type in general?

Usage example:

> It is better to use _________ connectors, as they ensure that network is less likely to become accidentally disconnected.

Comment: I've worked with electrical and electronic stuff for about 60 years, and I've never encountered an "official" term.  "Locking", "latching", "screw on", "screw in", "twist-lock", etc, would be used, depending on the specifics of the design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are known as *latching* connectors. The *latch* prevents the connector from being accidentally disconnected. Modular connectors such as the RJ45 have simple [plastic tabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#Latching_tab_and_orientation) that act as latches. These latches are easily broken, and other types of connectors may use more robust latches. For example, the [XLR connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLR_connector) used in professional audio equipment has metal latches.

> [**latch**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/latch) noun
>
> 1. A metal bar with a catch and lever used for fastening a door or gate:
>
>    - Lifting the latch, she pushed the gate open.

Oxford Dictionaries